# Ruby 2.0.0 cannot load such file even though gem is installed

Tags: ruby, rubygems, executable, require, ruby-2.0

I've tried all of the other solutions people have talked about on here, but none of them have helped / applied.

I've written a Ruby script that requires the spreadsheet gem. The requiring works fine when I execute the script normally with `ruby myscript.rb`, but after running `chmod +x myscript.rb`, and then trying to run the program with `./myscript.rb` I get the following error....

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require': cannot load such file -- spreadsheet (LoadError)
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require'
from /Users/fcangialosi/dev/mTC/parse.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require'
from /Users/fcangialosi/dev/mTC/interpreter.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require'
from ./pmcnp.rb:7:in `<main>'
```

The beginning of my script looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

require 'rubygems'
require 'spreadsheet'
```

If anyone has any ideas, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Try `chmod +r myscript.rb`.

Comment: tried that, now I get this error...
`./mparse.rb: line 5: require: command not found
./mparse.rb: line 7: interpreter: command not found
./mparse.rb: line 8: interpreter.start: command not found`

Comment: What does running `which ruby` return?

Comment: `which ruby`

`/Users/fcangialosi/.rbenv/shims/ruby`

Comment: If you're building a gem and you run into this problem, it's because the gem is not in your Gemspec or Gemfile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your answers to the comments, the ruby you're running normally - and therefore the one in which your gems are installed - is `/Users/fcangialosi/.rbenv/shims/ruby`. When you make the script executable, it uses the hint in the script to know which program to use to execute the script. In your case, you have:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
```

So that's using whichever ruby version you have installed in `/usr/bin/ruby`. In order to use your rbenv ruby instead of `/usr/bin/ruby`, change the shebang line to:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
```

Comment: now I know what's the difference between `/usr/bin/*` and `/usr/bin/env *` '__')b