# Cannot load such file `Tokyo-Rufus` even though Gem is included

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundle, ruby-2.0, foreman

I am trying to create a simple Sinatra app.  I wanted to add user authentication using Sinatra-Authentication.  I have been using their github [site](https://github.com/maxjustus/sinatra-authentication) and this [blog](http://phamlabs.com/2013/03/17/Adding-the-sinatra-authentication-Gem.html).  I used the 2nd example using Tokyo-Rufus.

However, now when I try to start up my app using **foreman start** I get the following error:

```
foreman start
23:42:30 web.1  | started with pid 6394
23:42:30 web.1  | web.rb:2:in `require': cannot load such file -- rufus_tokyo (LoadError)
23:42:30 web.1  |   from web.rb:2:in `<main>'
23:42:30 web.1  | exited with code 1
23:42:30 system | sending SIGTERM to all processes
SIGTERM received
```

My web.rb looks like this (following the instructions on their github site):

```
require 'sinatra'
require "rufus_tokyo"
require "digest/sha1"
require 'rack-flash'
require "sinatra-authentication"

TcUserTable.cabinet_path = File.dirname(__FILE__) + 'db'

use Rack::Session::Cookie, :secret => 'A secret cookie'
use Rack::Flash

get '/' do
  erb :index
end
```

So it is obvious that it is failing when it is trying to load the rufus-tokyo gem.  However when I do a bundle list I get:

```
Gems included by the bundle:
  * rufus-tokyo (1.0.7)
```

...so it should be included.  I am using Ruby 2.0 and saw on [Ruby 2.0.0 cannot load such file even though gem is installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19580729/ruby-2-0-0-cannot-load-such-file-even-though-gem-is-installed) that they were using the wrong version of ruby... but when I do **ruby -v** I get

```
ruby 2.0.0p0 (2013-02-24 revision 39474) [x86_64-darwin13.2.0]
```

So I think I am using the correct version of Ruby as well.  Any ideas on why I would be getting this error would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: Looking at the [`rufus-tokyo`](https://github.com/jmettraux/rufus-tokyo/) repo it should be `require 'rufus/tokyo'` or `require 'rufus-tokyo'`, not `rufus_tokyo`. It looks like a typo.

Comment: Wow sometimes the simplest things.  Thank you very much.